# Is there a way to tell the browser to clear cache upon loading a page?

Tags: html, caching

We have certain pages that get updated often. However, the images are cached and sometimes, the old banners/images are the ones being viewed by some people. This is crucial because some of the banners contain 1-day promotions. If the older images are the ones being viewed, then we aren't able to communicate to them about the promotion.

This also happens to CSS. Sometimes, we update the CSS but even after a couple of refreshes, the old CSS is still the one being loaded.

Is there a way to prevent these from happening?

Comment: what serverside scripting language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

[Avoid CSS Caching](http://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following it should prevent images and css from caching:

```
<img src="some.gif?t=<?php echo uniqid();?>" />
<link href="some.css?t=<?php echo uniqid();?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using this code if working with c#

```
// Disable CACHE of browser
            //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
            //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
            //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
            //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```